# How to fix "line is too long" error given by lint command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

My lint program says this line is too long:

```
@abc = @def.model_name.where(id: @ghi.id).sum(:jkl) unless @ghi.blank?
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: huh? Make the line shorter or change your linter's sensitivity.

Comment: Just break it before any dot or consider extracting that logic into a method

Comment: @kaikuchn: better break _after_ dots. More IRB friendly.

Comment: You are right, however I think that by default rubocop complains about line breaks after dots, doesn't it? Assuming his linter is rubocop he might get yet another warning.

Comment: Rubocop doesn't complain about line breaks if the line begins with a dot and is aligned with the prior statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while but fixed it

```
@abc = @def.model_name.where(
         id: @ghi.id).sum(:jkl) unless @ghi.blank?
```

Comment: Please don't post your final code unless this is your accepted answer. If it is to be your accepted answer then you need to explain why you're doing so and explain how it works. Adding the "final solution" as an answer doesn't really help provide clarity and in some discussions about this type of answer they've said it actually hurts the value of the question by distracting from the answer that actually solved the problem.

Comment: I think the other other suggestions made are much easier for a stranger to read (including yourself if you come back to this code in a year's time).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to make the line shorter.

```
unless @ghi.blank?
  @abc = @def.model_name
             .where(id: @ghi.id)
             .sum(:jkl) 
end
```

This would be the generally accepted way of shortening the lines without refactoring more widely.

Also, it's just a linter. Your code will still work if you don't do as it says, it'll just be less readable.

Comment: Linters are there to help make us aware of potential problems, and to help enforce common coding practices among teams and the community in general. Line length is one of those things I twiddle because 70 characters is archaic. It's sensible if you're printing out code, but very few people do that these days. Instead we're looking at editors on monitors capable of displaying 255 characters. 255 is too long so I recommended our team use 132 as a happy medium.